# Se puede crear divs diferentes apartir de un array?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Hola queria saber si se podia crear diferentes divs para cada uno de los objetos, ya que cuando lo intento se me multiplica todo, soy nuevo en el tema, desde ya muchas gracias!

```
let mangas=[{nombre:"gantz",genero:"accion",precio:"500",img:"img/gantz.jpg"},

    {nombre:"kingdom",genero:"accion",precio:"900",img:"img/king.jpg"},
    {nombre:"dorohedoro",genero:"accion",precio:"400",img:"img/doro.jpg"},
    {nombre:"csm",genero:"accion",precio:"300",img:"img/csm.jpg"},]
mangas.forEach(elemento => {
$(`.lista`).append(`<div class="articulo"></div>`)
$(`.articulo`).append(`<img src="${elemento.img}">`)
$(`.articulo`).append(`<p class:"titulo">Nombre: ${elemento.nombre} - Genero: ${elemento.genero} </p>`)
$(`.articulo`).append(`<p class:"genero"> </p>`)

$(`.articulo`).append(`<p class:"precio">Precio: ${elemento.precio} </p>`)
$(`.articulo`).append(`<button class="boton">Agregar al carrito ${elemento.nombre}</button>`)});
```

Comment: Y donde está komi-san?!  Bueno, te recomiendo que leas [¿Cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Repuesta a tu pregunta -> Sí se puede. ¿podrías decir cual es el problema puntual que tienes?

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Comment: Saludos. A salvedad no leí bien tu código; crea un  **div** (no directamente como lo haces en el **$(`.lista`).append(`<div class="articulo"></div>`)** ) a ese le agregas los elementos y al final lo agregas a tu **lista**.

Comment: ¿Cómo vas a hacer los divs? ¿Quieres que muestren los datos o cómo?

Answer (score 0):

Si se puede, aca te dejo como un poco mas simplificado.

```js
let mangas=[
    {nombre:"gantz",genero:"accion",precio:"500",img:"img/gantz.jpg"},
    {nombre:"kingdom",genero:"accion",precio:"900",img:"img/king.jpg"},
    {nombre:"dorohedoro",genero:"accion",precio:"400",img:"img/doro.jpg"},
    {nombre:"csm",genero:"accion",precio:"300",img:"img/csm.jpg"}
]
    
    
    
mangas.forEach(elemento =>
 $(".lista").append(`<div class="articulo">
                      <img src="${elemento.img}"/>
                      <p class:"titulo">Nombre: ${elemento.nombre} - Genero: ${elemento.genero} </p>
                      <p class:"genero"> </p>
                      <p class:"precio">Precio: ${elemento.precio} </p>
                      <button class="boton">Agregar al carrito ${elemento.nombre}</button>
                  </div>`)
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="lista">
 <!-- aca va a ir todo el contenido -->
</div>
```